# How to repeat python lines for running commands?

Tags: python

I'm beginner on python, and i tried to repeat my python command from line 3 until line 7 on this code

```
print("Hello")
print("World")
print("Foo")
print("Foo")
print("Foo")
print("Foo")
print("Foo")
```

but i don't want to repeat that foo for 4 times, i want to make it shorter like this

```
print("Hello")
print("World")
print("Foo")
print ln 3 * 4 times again
```

but it did't work(yeah i know it supposed to be not worked)

to someone who knows or can give the solution please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop to repeat the command. Try:

```
print("Hello")
print("World")
for x in range(5):
    print("Foo")
```

Comment: should be 5, not 4: `for x in range(5):`

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Reddy Lutonadio is correct, but the code below is a little shorter and teaches some concepts about Python Lists:

```py
for s in ["Hello", "World"] + ["Foo"]*5:
    print(s)
```

Or, even shorter:

```py
print("\n".join(["Hello", "World"] + ["Foo"]*5))
```

Comment: And further in learning to program; find the available options and then use one that makes the code easily understandable and also easy to modify; e.g. You yourself must understand what is intended to happen after not looking at it for a year or so.